# probleam with dispatch typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try to send this dispatch but it gives me this error (and all my other dispatches also have the same problem):

Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action'

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTodos(findError));
  }, []);
```

This would be my action, in which the dispatch is executed:

```
type Error = (err: null | string) => void

export const getTodos = (findError: Error) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>): Promise<Action> => {
    try {
      findError(null);
      const response = await axios(`...`);
      const result: TodoItem[] = response.data;

      return dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.GET_TODOS,
        payload: result,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      findError("Ha ocurrido un error al cargar las tareas");
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

and this would be the Action object that appears in all my code:

```
import { TodoItem } from "types/interfaces/interfaces.actions";
import { ActionTypes } from "redux/actions-types";

export interface GetTodos {
  type: ActionTypes.GET_TODOS;
  payload: TodoItem[];
}

export interface DeleteTodo {
  type: ActionTypes.DELETE_TODO;
  payload: number | string;
}

export interface PutTodo{
  type: ActionTypes.PUT_TODO,
  payload: PutTodoData
}

interface PutTodoData {
  id: number | string;
  checked: boolean;
}

export interface PostTodo{
  type: ActionTypes.POST_TODO,
  payload: TodoItem
}

export interface OrderTodo{
  type: ActionTypes.ORDER_TODO,
  payload: TodoItem[]
}

export type Action = GetTodos | DeleteTodo | PutTodo | PostTodo | OrderTodo;
```

I really have no idea what it could be, I tried everything, to dispatch I use useAppDispatch too. And it is well implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the Dispatch type in your action function's return statement is not compatible with the Dispatch type that you're using in your useEffect hook.

One way to fix this is to specify the ThunkDispatch type from the redux-thunk library in your action function:

```
    import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
    import { Action } from './your-actions-file';

    export const getTodos = (findError: Error) => {
        return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, Action>): Promise<Action> => {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

The ThunkDispatch type extends Dispatch and provides an extra generic parameter for the thunk action type.

Using this type should allow your action function to be compatible with the Dispatch type in your useEffect hook, as well as any other places where you are using Dispatch.

Additionally, you should provide the dependencies array for your useEffect hook to prevent unnecessary rerenders and make sure that dispatch and findError are accessible:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTodos(findError));
}, [dispatch, findError]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems to be close but now it gives this error:
(alias) getTodos(findError: Error): (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, Action>) => Promise<Action>
import getTodos

Argument of type '(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, Action>) => Promise<Action>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action'.ts(2345)

I don't understand what is wrong because it basically returns the same thing now

Comment: The problem is that if I hover on the dispatch of dispatch(...), it tells me that it is of type Dispatch